# Why did uninstalling Wubi not free disk space while virtual hard disk was 15GB?

Tags: wubi, uninstall

We recently uninstalled Wubi from a Windows Vista computer by selecting Ubuntu in Control Panel and clicking the uninstall button. The uninstaller ran suspiciously fast (it was done in a few seconds while Wubi's virtual hard disk was something like 15GB large), and after checking disk usage, no disk space was freed despite C:\ubuntu isn't there anymore.

Why did uninstalling it not free any disk space and how can I get my disk space back?

Comment: Did you have problems with the Wubi install? Sometimes, if corrupted, the `root.disk` (the 15 GB file) will be recovered to the hidden and protected `\found.000` folder by `chkdsk`. If there's nothing there, then everything will have been removed.

Comment: @bcbc The last time the Wubi installation was quit, it was done with a forced hold-down-the-power-button shutdown. (We knew it was bad and could corrupt `root.disk`, but we had no choice and there was no important data in it anyway) We never tried to start it up again, so there's a pretty good chance it was corrupted indeed. Could it be that then? Where is that folder? And how can I delete the file from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, uninstalling Wubi from the *Control Panel*, *Add/remove programs*, the *Ubuntu* entry, will completely remove it. In some cases, uninstalling might fail, but it's unlikely for it to succeed and not free up space.

In rare cases, if your Wubi install is corrupted, Windows may automatically run `chkdsk` (which you should notice when Windows boots if you are watching it) and in that case it could recover the virtual disk to a hidden `\found.???` folder on the drive that Wubi is installed on. If this happens you would probably have had issues booting the Wubi install (probably stuck at a grub prompt).

To delete this leftover virtual disk (don't do this if you have data you want to recover), run `CMD.EXE` as an administrator (right click on it and select "Run as administrator"). Change to the drive the `\ubuntu` directory was on, and search for the hidden `\found.???` directories. And then delete the files to free up space.

```
C:\>dir /a:h
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 20A3-F99V

 Directory of C:\

2013-01-16  08:42 PM    <DIR>          $Recycle.Bin
2012-05-18  10:08 PM           389,720 bootmgr
2012-06-02  07:30 AM                 1 BOOTNXT
2012-07-26  12:22 AM    <JUNCTION>     Documents and Settings [C:\Users]
2013-01-15  05:08 PM    <DIR>          ESD
2013-01-15  05:08 PM    <DIR>          found.000
2013-05-10  03:50 PM     5,065,179,136 hiberfil.sys
2013-05-10  03:51 PM     1,006,632,960 pagefile.sys
2013-04-12  11:47 AM    <DIR>          ProgramData
2013-05-10  03:51 PM       268,435,456 swapfile.sys
2013-05-14  10:57 AM    <DIR>          System Volume Information
               5 File(s)  6,340,637,273 bytes
               6 Dir(s)   8,312,860,672 bytes free


C:\>cd \found.000
C:\found.000>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 20A3-F99V

 Directory of C:\found.000

19/07/2011  02:02 PM    15,000,000,000 file0000.chk
               1 File(s) 15,000,000,000 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  222,258,069,504 bytes free

C:\found.000>del file0000.chk
```

If the whole `\ubuntu\disks` directory was corrupted, you're looking for a directory named `dir0000.chk`, and inside that you'll find the correctly named `root.disk` and `swap.disk`:

```
C:\>cd found.000

C:\found.000>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 20A3-F99V

 Directory of C:\found.000

19/10/2012  04:51 PM    <DIR>          .
19/10/2012  04:51 PM    <DIR>          ..
19/07/2011  02:02 PM    <DIR>          dir0000.chk
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  222,258,069,504 bytes free

C:\found.000>dir dir0000.chk
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 20A3-F99V

 Directory of C:\found.000\dir0000.chk

19/10/2012  04:51 PM    <DIR>          .
19/10/2012  04:51 PM    <DIR>          ..
24/02/2012  12:22 AM    <DIR>          boot
06/11/2012  09:28 AM    13,000,000,000 root.disk
15/11/2011  09:28 PM       268,435,456 swap.disk
               2 File(s) 13,268,435,456 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  127,904,968,704 bytes free

C:\>DEL \found.000\dir0000.chk\root.disk
```

Etc. (delete others and remove the directories)

If you find nothing, then most likely you are mistaken about the space.

Comment: There where no `\found.xxx` folders... Must be a misconseption of me then. Thanks!